# Displaying .mht file in html module in DNN

Tags: iframe, dotnetnuke, mhtml

In our DNN site we need to display many .mht files in the html module. I did it by iframe tag, but the file is not loading when the site is browsed for first time or when the page is refreshed by Ctrl+F5. When the page is refreshed second time by F5 the files are loaded and displayed. Why are the files not loading when the page is browsed the first time.

Also, I uploaded the mht file to the server through FTP, is there any other way to upload the mht file to the server

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, you should be able to upload the files via the File Manager (Admin -> File Manager), though you may need to update the list of allowed file extensions on the Host Settings page first (in the Other Settings section).